# Logo and text in same line - bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can anyone tell me on why my text collapses when viewed in higher resolution and not in mobile resolution?.

I want to achieve something like above, below is what i have tried.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-4">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </button>
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Big Google</a>
                  <a class="navbar-brand divider-vertical" href="#">Chicago - Newyork</a>
                </div>
            </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Below is a fiddle link to play with. Can anyone tell me on why my text collapses when viewed in higher resolution and not in mobile resolution and also am i creating the text and brand name in correct manner?.
http://www.bootply.com/abKYgnFwAj

Comment: There is a `width` setting for `.col-sm-4` and that seems to be the cause. Over-riding it like `.col-sm-4 {width: auto;}` fixes the issue.  Check if you are ok doing this. If yes, I will add it as answer. Sample [here](http://www.bootply.com/rHtLm3byRr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of bootstrap's default settings.

There is a `width` setting for `.col-sm-4` within `@media (min-width: 768px)` in the bootstrap CSS. This sets the `width` of the entire `div` to 33.33333333% (1/3rd of total screen width) when the screen width is at least 768px (or higher).

Because of this for a normal screen, the width of this section becomes (1024/3)px and this is not enough to fit the logo's width and the width of the other part in the same line.

When the width is enough to fit the entire content on the same line, it works fine. For example, my screen width is 1600px, so the width of this div becomes 533px and it is enough to accommodate both in the same line.

Below a screen width of 768px, it doesn't assign any specific width (meaning it takes entire available width) and hence you don't see any wrap around. If you add a couple more links you will see the same behavior for this also because with 4 links the total width exceeds the available screen width and hence the contents wrap around to the next line.

If you don't want it ever to be assigned any specific width, then you can just over-ride it by adding the below:

```
.col-sm-4{
    width: auto;
}
```

Or, if you want to assign a specific width for resolutions exceeding 1024px, you can use the following media query.

```
@media (min-width: 1025px) {
  .col-sm-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  }
}
```

[**Sample Demo**](http://www.bootply.com/mS5K09YftW)

Comment: Thanks Harry again. I did not apply your code as it causes some shrinking while re-sizing. http://www.bootply.com/l1LMFfMIsI# Can you let me know if this is fine? ie... responsive....

Comment: Looks good mate. You seem to be a quick learner :) But I hope you did intend to hide the storage/volume details at lower resolutions.

Comment: Yup, that was with intention... Thanks harry for your help and time. Note: I did not apply your code, that's fine right?.

Comment: @theJava: Great. No worries about not using my code. We are just here to try and help but you should only use what suits your needs :) I included those samples only for extra information/illustration.

Comment: One question, how would write media queries for these two resolutions.... 768*1024 and 800 *1280.. could you share some link or fiddle where i can capture different resolutions... thanks.

Comment: @theJava: You will find this [CSS Trick Demo](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) useful.

Answer (score -1):

When I changed the CSS in your example to this it looked like you wanted it to look.

```
.divider-vertical {
    height: 50px;
    border-left: 1px solid #a8a8a8;
    border-right: 1px solid #a8a8a8;
}
```

My guess is that the different margin's within the navbar cause the second child to be pushed to the next line, but I might be wrong. It works anyway. I hope this helps, good luck!